# Laravel 5.6. Fail, if 2 specific fields are present in the request

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.6, laravel-validation

I have 2 fields in the request. `field1` and `field2`.

What rules should I define in the `FormRequest` to fail validation, if both are present?

Comment: Show us what you have tried, if nothing else it helps us to understand the question

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/master/validation#rule-required-without

Comment: If you don't want them to be required, you can write a custom rule.

Comment: @anyber `required_without` is not working, when both fields are present. And I need something like `fail_with` or `fail_if_present`. I just thought I have overlooked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AFAIK there is no validation rule for this, you could write one, or if it's one-off, you could write a closure:

```
    'field1' => function ($attribute, $value, $fail) {
        if ($value && $this->input('field2')) {
            return $fail($attribute.' can only be filled when field2 is empty.');
        }
    },
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/validation#using-closures

Note: Outside of a FormRequest class, you would need to use something other than `$this->input()`

Comment: 1. Thanks a lot for you answer. This is what I needed. 2. Creating a `Validator::` rule and posting it here may be helpful for other people and may help you receive even more upvotes than just from me :)